# How to resolve this error in springMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]

Comment: can paste the headers part of your xml

Comment: Short answer: use the correct syntax in the spring XML configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use the correct syntax in the spring XML configuration file.

Here is an example that includes the context schema:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

... config stuff

</beans>
```